# Backup Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy settings

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

Is there a specific way to backup the "Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy" settings on Jenkins ver 2.x?
I know I can backup using thin backup or just the xml files, but I am looking for a way that will handle this specific action either by script or plugin (couldn't find any plugin)

Update: I've now learned that once it is enabled, both globally & job wise,
The job configuration will remain after the global configuration have been disabled, and then reinstated.   but I would still very much like to know if there an answer to my question.